# CRM 2011 error: The communication object cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state

Tags: c#, web-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I get this error on my CRM organisation and all the plugins stopped working.
They have always been working without a problem so far. Restarting the service and the machine does not seem to help.
I was working with a new plugin this morning when it stopped working and I realised the other ones were not working any longer. I tried to deactivate and remove the new plugin with no avail.
Here is the trace:

```
[2014-03-31 13:59:28.211] Process:Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.HostService |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   13 |Category: Sandbox |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Warning |ReqId:  | SandboxClientBase`1.Stop  ilOffset = 0xD
>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxClientBase`1.Stop()
[2014-03-31 14:08:37.953] Process:Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.HostService |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   15 |Category: Sandbox |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Warning |ReqId:  | SandboxErrorHandler.HandleError  ilOffset = 0xE
>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.ReadAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.EndRead()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
# CRM Tracing Version 2.0
# LocalTime: 2014-03-31 14:09:22.932
# Categories: *:Warning
# CallStackOn: No
# ComputerName: KASUMIACC
# CRMVersion: 5.0.9910.0014
```

UPDATE 1

There was a plugin calling a WS, so the error from the Pipe was due to that. I deactivated that plugin and now the error I am getting when the service starts is:

```
[2014-03-31 14:46:51.239] Process:Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.HostService |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   11 |Category: Sandbox |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Warning |ReqId:  | SandboxClientBase`1.Stop  ilOffset = 0xD
>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException: The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Close()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxClientBase`1.Stop()
```

UPDATE 2

I used Powershell to set the SPN for the MSCRMSandboxService

```
setspn -A MSCRMSandboxService/localhost ACCOUNTNAME
```

And verified it with

```
setspn -L AccountName
```

Everything seemed ok, but it didn't help.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using named pipes?

Comment: From 2nd stacktrace it appears that the error is thrown while closing the IOrganizationService proxy. Are you initializing service object inside "Using" block or calling Close() method on the service object in any of your plugins or custom workflow activity? If yes, try removing those and then you will get the real exception.